# If $n$ and $m$ are integers and $d$ is their $GCF$, prove all factors of $n$ and$ m$ are factors of $d$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here's what I know:

The basic outline of the proof. I know how to do the proof, but one part doesn't click with me. That is, how do we know that the GCF's prime factorization, and all of its subdivisions into factors, represents all the factors of n and m?

Something I proved that may help: If n and m are integers and d is their GCF, then all the factors of d are factors of n and m.

The reason for the above is that any factors of d have an integer they can be multiplied by to get d by definition. And d, by definition of GCF, has integers that can multiply with it to get n and m. Therefore, all factors of d are factors of n and m.

My question basically says - ok, given the above, how do you prove that the factors of GCF are ALL the factors of n and m?

My attempt at proving it involves tackling the issue at heart - that is, how do you know that from the prime factorization of a number you can create all its factors by combinations of different parts of it? I still haven't been able to prove this core issue.

Thanks!

Comment: To answer the question in your final paragraph: it is an immediate consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, i.e. the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations.

Comment: We know from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra that every number is expressible as a unique multiplication of prime numbers (numbers greater than 1, that is). But how does this imply that the prime factorization of a number contains the components for creating all of its factors?

Comment: If not then one easily obtains a nonunique factorization - think about it. Btw, it's the Fundamental Theorem of *Arithmetic*, not *Algebra*.

Comment: How does the existence of other factors that are not makable from the prime factorization imply a non-unique factorization?

Comment: Extend those factors to a complete factorization into primes, then compare it to the original factorization.

Comment: So there's no standardized way to prove it? Just empirical?

Comment: Why do you think that? All of the results you mention can be proved  rigorously. If you tell me precisely where you are stuck then I can elaborate.

Comment: I am stuck precisely on the point where we are talking about the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Why is it that if all factors of a number cannot be expressed as a combination of the primes in the number's prime factorization, the factorization is not unique?

Comment: If $\,a\mid c = p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n}$ then $\,ab=c\,$ for some $\,b\in\Bbb Z.\,$ Appending the prime factorizations of $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ gives another prime factorization of $\,c.\,$ By uniqueness, the same set of primes occur, and if the powers of $\,p\,$ in $\,a,b,c\,$ are $\,i,j,k\,$ then $\,i+j = k.\,$ Therefore the factors of $c$ are precisely the integers of form $\pm p_1^{f_1}\cdots p_n^{f_n}$ where $\,f_i \le e_i.\ \ $

Comment: Can you please clarify what the notation of ±pf11⋯pfnn means? Sorry for the confusing blurb before, I don't know how to get it into your form.

Comment: $\pm m\,$ means $\,m\,$ or $\,-m.\,$ I appended the sign in case you are considering negative factors also.

Comment: I wasn't talking about that - I was talking about the superscript e sub 1 and 3 sub n. Anyway, I figured it out on my own, so I think I'll share a way simpler reasoning to prove the last clause:

Comment: 1. p(n) = n, by definition (p(n) is the prime factorization of n)
2. we know that k is a factor of n, by definition
3. So, k must be a factor of p(n), since p(n) = n                  So now taking this back to the original problem, since the common factors of n and m must be formed from the common bases, and d includes the highest powers of all common bases, we know that all common factors of n and m are factors of d.

Comment: There are many ways to prove the OP. As I said, my comment was in reply to the question in your final paragraph (even though that is not needed for the OP).